# Is it possible to place cells automatically on the next row while using css grid areas?

Tags: html, css, sass, grid, css-grid

I'm using css grid for a new project and i came across a "problem". I've read the documentation but maybe i'm missing something.

**Current situation**

I've created a css grid with two columns. The left column is the "main" column and the right column is the "side" column. If i put the divs alternately after each other, each cell will be placed to the next row automatically. This works fine:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid__cell {
  height: 50px;
}

.main {
  background: blue;
}

.side {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
</div>
```

**Goal**

Now i want to create template-areas for both columns. This way it's easier to put a certain cell in the right column and the order of the divs in the html doesn't matter anymore. The problem is that when i'm using template-areas, all the cells will start at the first row:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  
  grid-template-areas: "main side";
}

.grid__cell {
  height: 50px;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  
  background: blue;
}

.side {
  grid-area: side;
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
</div>
```

I know i can use `grid-row` to place the cell to a specific row, but that's not the ideal situation. It would be nice if the cells will be placed automatically to the next row in the right column. Am i missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use `grid-area` for this, use [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) for an auto-flow placement.
if it happens that you see some holes, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow (keyword:dense)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid__cell {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.main {
  grid-column: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.side {
  grid-column: 2;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="grid__cell side">
    side
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "grid-auto-flow: row dense;" is the solution. It even works with grid-template-areas. You have to add grid-row-start: auto; and grid-row-end: auto; tho. Thanks!